# Convert Hexa array to String

Tags: python

I need convert this array

```
data = [
#SHO
0x56, 0x0d, 
#CMD
0x1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
#ARG
0x1, 0x0,
#SIZE
0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
#OPAQUE
0x01, 0x02,
#RESERVED
0x00, 0x00
]
```

and produce a string

```
# converted data into s
print s
```

Comment: Can we get some sample output for the data shown please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [16]: ''.join(str(i) for i in data)
Out[16]: '861310001020001200'
```

or (as perhaps as per @thg435's suggestion) using `chr()` in place of `str()`:

```
In [25]: ''.join(chr(i) for i in data)
Out[25]: 'V\r\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00'
```

Is this what you are looking for? If not, can you provide the desired output?

Comment: @thg435 Thanks, I appreciate the suggestion (and interpretation :)  .. I'll add this to my answer if you don't mind .. the spec is a bit ambiguous

Comment: @thg435 My thanks to you for reading this the right way.  If you wanted to add this as your own answer and get the credit, I'd happy edit my own answer back to its previous state .. just let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean to read it as string of bytes?

```
print bytearray(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Combining the current posts since the question is ambiguous.)

Printing the bytes in hex:

```
>>> ''.join(('%2s' % hex(d)[2:]).replace(' ', '0') for d in data)
'560d0100000001000200000001020000'
```

Printing the bytes as decimal:

```
>>> ''.join(str(i) for i in data)
'861310001020001200'
```

Printing the bytes as characters:

```
>>> print bytearray(data)
☺   ☺ ☻   ☺☻
```

or equivalently:

```
>>> print ''.join(map(chr, data))
☺   ☺ ☻   ☺☻
```